# Put method doesnt work in Flutter but perfectly ok in Postman

Tags: flutter, dart, heroku-api

I tried an API endpoint with Postman and the Put Method works perfectly but In flutter, it doesn't update the field in textfromfield.  tried every possible solution, A life-changing help

```
  void UpdateTask(int id, String a, String b) {
    var updateUrl =
        Uri.parse('https:........./api/update/${id}/');
    setState(() {
      widget.client.put(
        updateUrl,
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          "Title": a,
          "Desc": b,
        }),
      );
    });

    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
class UpdatePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String Desc;
  final int idoftask;
  final Client client;

  const UpdatePage({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.Desc,
    required this.idoftask,
    required this.client,
  });

  @override
  State<UpdatePage> createState() => _UpdatePageState();
}

class _UpdatePageState extends State<UpdatePage> {
  TextEditingController taskEditingController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController desEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    taskEditingController.text = widget.title;
    desEditingController.text = widget.Desc;

    super.initState();
  }

  void UpdateTask(int id, String a, String b) {
    var updateUrl =
        Uri.parse('https://-------/api/update/${id}/');
    setState(() {
      widget.client.put(
        updateUrl,
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          "Title": a,
          "Desc": b,
        }),
      );
    });

    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'UPDATE THE TASK',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18, horizontal: 25),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: taskEditingController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Task',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            TextFormField(
              controller: desEditingController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Description',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (() => UpdateTask(
                    widget.idoftask,
                    taskEditingController.text,
                    desEditingController.text,
                  )),
              child: Text('Edit '),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

changes based on other  @Idriss and other SOF threads.Now working

```
Future<void> UpdateTask(int id, String a, String b) async {
var updateUrl =
    Uri.parse('https://todobackenda.herokuapp.com/api/update/${id}/');
final response = await widget.client.put(
  updateUrl,
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: jsonEncode({
    "Title": a,
    "Desc": b,
  }),
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(response.body);
  setState(() {});
}
Navigator.pop(context);
```

}

```
  onPressed: (() async {
                await UpdateTask(
                  widget.idoftask,
                  taskEditingController.text,
                  desEditingController.text,
                );
              }),`enter code here`
```

Add all other methods ( GET. DELETE. CREATE . )works but the PUT .. aLSO put method works in Postman. aLSO, put method works in Postman
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to await your api call, after that you can reload your page.

SO you have to do :

```
  onPressed: (() async {
       var response = await widget.client.put(
       updateUrl,
       headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
       },
       body: jsonEncode({
       "Title": a,
            "Desc": b,
       }),
    ); 
    if (response.statusCode == 200){
       setState(() { 
         ...
       }  
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, But didn't work. Tried it

Comment: Any other problem with code. ? Really appreciate it for the help

Comment: when you call the UpdateTask() method, your taskEditingController value is good ?

Comment: Yes , I actually added a print function to see if new update value will go through , and it's ok but not sure whyyyy it doent show up in the main page and on server

Comment: the server receive the call ?

Comment: Yessss, Now i have it , Really appreciate it , I also added the asyn and await in the Elevated button as well

Comment: If you add the onPressed section in your answer,I will mark it as the correct answer. Really appreacite it .